Eigendecomposition of a non-uniform finite difference matrix
I have the following matrix (derived from a finite difference approximating the second derivative on a non-uniform grid):
$$A=DL = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{h_0+h_1} & && \\
& \frac{1}{h_1+h_2} && \\
&& \ddots && \\
&&& \frac{1}{h_{n-2}+h_{n-1}} & \\
&&&& \frac{1}{h_{n-1}+h_0}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
-\frac{h_0+h_1}{h_0h_1} & \frac{1}{h_1} & & & \frac{1}{h_0}\\
\frac{1}{h_1} & -\frac{h_1+h_2}{h_1h_2} & \frac{1}{h_2} &&   \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \\
&& \frac{1}{h_{n-2}} & -\frac{h_{n-2}+h_{n-1}}{h_{n-2}h_{n-1}} & \frac{1}{h_{n-1}} \\
\frac{1}{h_0}&&& \frac{1}{h_{n-1}} & -\frac{h_{n-1} + h_0}{h_{n-1}h_0}  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
When $h_i = h$, the eigendecomposition is given through the DFT and the eigenvalues are $\lambda_j = 2-2\cos(\theta_j)$ where $\theta_j = 2\pi j/n$ for $0\leq j \leq n-1$. My question is whether the structure of the above matrix (either $A$ or just $L$) allows for a closed form expression for its eigendecomposition. I know that for arbitrary tridiagonal symmetric matrices this is intractable, but I was hoping that maybe the above structure could somehow be leveraged to get a closed form expression for the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues. I was thinking that maybe the non-uniform DFT (or its inverse) could be a likely candidate, but I did not manage to show this (it may very well be false).
